# excel vba to open webpage with 3 drop down list. How to select from 2 drop list with the first item listed

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I have to copy and paste a webpage daily. The webpage has 2 drop down list. 1 list for date and another list for time. Can someone advise how to write a code to choose the date and the time on vba macro.

I need to choose in list 1, the first date (i.e yesterday's date) and list 2, time (i.e All)

See below for drop down list. I am using internet explorer 8
List 1:
Date:
13/3/2011(yesterday date)
14/3/2011(today date)
15/3/2011(tommorrow date)

List 2:
Time:
-All- (list all the events in the time)
00:00 to 01:59 (list only events in 00:01:59)
02:00 to 02:59

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying this to work for you:

```
Sub test

  dim IE as InternetExplorerMedium

  set IE = new InternetExplorerMedium

  IE.navigate "stackoverflow.com" 'Replace SO with your required page

  IE.document.getElementById("combo box 1").value = format(date - 1, "d/m/yyyy")
  IE.document.getElementById("combo box 2").value = format(date - 1, "d/m/yyyy")

  set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit: You'll need to find the ids of the boxes you want to enter information in by viewing the source of the page. Replace "combo box 1" and "combo box 2" with these values.

Edit 2: You'll also need to set a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls